# Left / Right Functions in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm working in Excel and I have this formula :

```
=IF(B9="1","1/1",IF(B9="2","1 & 2",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("/",B9)),B9,
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-",B9)),LEFT(B9,FIND("-",B9)-1)&" thru 
"&RIGHT(B9,FIND("-",B9)-1),"1 thru "&VALUE(B9)))))

where B9="9-24"
```

Why does this formula output `"9 thru 4"`?

I want it to output "9 thru 24".  It's weird because `if B9="18-24"`, for example, then this formula correctly spits out `"18 thru 24"`.

There seems to be an issue, however, if the number preceding the dash is a single digit number.  And I'm stuck.

Answer (score 6):

So the bit of that long formula that is actually relevant is:

`LEFT(B9,FIND("-",B9)-1) & " thru " & RIGHT(B9,FIND("-",B9)-1)`

If B9 contains the text "9-24" (without the quotes) then `FIND("-",B9)` gives 2.

So your formula becomes 
`LEFT(B9,1) & " thru " & RIGHT(B9,1)`

which gives you the left most single character and the right most single character, so "9 thru 4".

If B9 contains the text "18-24" (without the quotes) then `FIND("-",B9)` gives 3 and you get the left most two characters and the right most two characters.

If you want the parts of the cell before and after the "-", you need to change the "RIGHT" part of your formula to:

```
RIGHT(B9,LEN(B9) - FIND("-",B9))
```

Comment: I wonder what he/she was actually trying to accomplish with this long formula. Was it just to replace "-" with " thru "? Because then obviously he/she could have just used =SUBSTITUTE(B9,"-"," thru ")

Comment: @Stepan1010, I don't think it was just that - the formula has lots of other options in there depending on exactly what is contained within B9.

Comment: You're probably right, but I try not to underestimate people's ability to over-complicate extremely simple things they are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `RIGHT()` where you should be using `MID()`.  To use `MID()`, you need a third argument long enough to capture everything after the dash.  This works:

```
=IF(B9="1","1/1",IF(B9="2","1 & 2",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("/",B9)),B9,
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-",B9)),LEFT(B9,FIND("-",B9)-1)&" thru 
"&MID(B9,FIND("-",B9)-1,99),"1 thru "&VALUE(B9)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `RIGHT` will return the rightmost characters of the string.  For example:

```
RIGHT("hello", 1)
```

Will return `o`.

In your function, you are doing the following:

```
RIGHT(B9,FIND("-",B9)-1)
```

This is taking the position of "-" subtract 1 as the number of characters to use from the right.  So you are using the length of the first number as the length for the second number.

Instead, you should be going the following:

```
RIGHT(B9,LEN(B9)-FIND("-",B9))
```

This will get you the rightmost characters after the "-".